# Integration problem in R when I use the function "integrate"

Tags: r, integrate

I'm trying to compute a kind of Gini index using a generated dataset.
But, I got a problem in the last integrate function.
If I try to integrate the function named f1,
R says

```
Error in integrate(Q, 0, p) : length(upper) == 1 is not TRUE
```

My code is

```
# set up parameters b>a>1 and the number of observations n
n <- 1000
a <- 2
b <- 4

# generate x and y
# where x follows beta distribution
# y = 10x+3
x <- rbeta(n,a,b)
y <- 10*x+3

# the starting point of the integration having problem
Q <- function(q) {
  quantile(y,q)
}

# integrate the function Q from 0 to p
G <- function(p) {
  integrate(Q,0,p)
}

# compute a function
L <- function(p) {
  numer <- G(p)$value
  dino <- G(1)$value
  numer/dino
}

# the part having problem
d <- 3
f1 <- function(p) {
  ((1-p)^(d-2))*L(p)
}
integrate(f1,0,1) # In this integration, the aforementioned error appears
```

I think, the repeated integrate could make a problem but I have no idea what is the exact problem.
Please help me!

Comment: `f1(0.1)` (for example) throws an error, so it seems a bit odd to try to integrate a function which itself needs debugging. `L(0.1)` also throws an error. Why not debug a function before trying to define other functions which use it?

Comment: This is a very odd problem. `Q` seems to act pathologically when integrated even though `curve(Q(x),0,1)` shows a fairly tame graph. I thought that the default `quantile` function gives a piecwise linear interpolation of the order statistics, so the behavior seems odd, perhaps even a bug in one of the R functions.

Comment: Playing around with this, if I comment out your last line, source it, and evaluate `integrate(Q,0,1)` roughly a third of the time I get the error message `Error in integrate(Q, 0, 1) : maximum number of subdivisions reached` but other times when I source it that error doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [@John Coleman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61273485/12158757), `integrate` needs to have a vectorized function and a proper `subdivisions` option to fulfill the integral task. Even if you have already provided a vectorized function for integral, it is sometimes tricky to properly set the `subdivisions` in `integrate(...,subdivisions = )`.

To address your problem, I recommend `integral` from package `pracma`, where you still a vectorized function for integral (see what I have done to functions `G` and `L`), but no need to set subdivisions manually, i.e.,

```
library(pracma)

# set up parameters b>a>1 and the number of observations n
n <- 1000
a <- 2
b <- 4

# generate x and y
# where x follows beta distribution
# y = 10x+3
x <- rbeta(n,a,b)
y <- 10*x+3

# the starting point of the integration having problem
Q <- function(q) {
  quantile(y,q)
}

# integrate the function Q from 0 to p
G <- function(p) {
  integral(Q,0,p)
}

# compute a function
L <- function(p) {
  numer <- Vectorize(G)(p)
  dino <- G(1)
  numer/dino
}

# the part having problem
d <- 3
f1 <- function(p) {
  ((1-p)^(d-2))*L(p)
}

res <- integral(f1,0,1)
```

then you will get

```
> res
[1] 0.1283569
```

Comment: Nice. Any idea for why `integrate` has problems with OP's `Q` function (at least at times)?

Comment: @JohnColeman `integrate` highly relies on `subdivisions` for some cases in my thought, I am not sure if that is the cause even if OP has already vectorized the function

Comment: Thank you so much! But, I got a new problem. This operation takes so long time and I have to repeat this calculation about 50 times in fact. In your case, was there no time-consuming problem??

Comment: @minchul yes, the same problem to me. It is caused by `Vectorize`, but I have no clue how to circumvent it. Maybe you can mathematically simplify the integral processes and retry if possible

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Okay, thank you again! Your solution is so nice!

Answer (score 1):

The error that you reported is due to the fact that the function in `integrate` must be vectorized and `integrate` itself isn't vectorized.

From the help (`?integrate`):

> f must accept a vector of inputs and produce a vector of function
>   evaluations at those points. The Vectorize function may be helpful to
>   convert f to this form.

Thus one "fix" is to replace your definition of `f1` by:

```
f1 <- Vectorize(function(p) {
  ((1-p)^(d-2))*L(p)
})
```

But when I run the resulting code I always get:

```
Error in integrate(Q, 0, p) : maximum number of subdivisions reached
```

A solution might be to assemble a large number of quantiles and then smooth it out and use that rather than your `Q`, although the error here strikes me as odd.